# How is this question off topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, hebrew

[Does the word X appear in Tanach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8173/does-the-word-toad-%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%A4%D7%93%D7%94-appear-in-tanach)

How could such a question be off topic? Tanach is squarely on topic, words in Tanach are squarely on topic. So what is the problem?

If it is motivation, then what is exactly is "on topic" motivation?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3346/tweaking-mi-yodeyas-scope-to-build-a-broader-community

Comment: I agree that it is on topic.

Comment: Oddly, that question has no reopen votes (at the moment).

Comment: @msh210 I voted to reopen. It won't let me vote again right now.

Comment: Me, too, @DoubleAA.

Comment: @msh210 So I've reopened it. (Also there were two reopen votes which had aged away some time ago.)

Comment: The record shows that I voted to close it, but I'm not sure why. Double AA mentioned some reopen votes that aged away; one of those may have been mine, but I don't remember.

Comment: Oh, I just checked; I did, indeed, vote to reopen. Not sure why it didn't clear review. Glad it was reopened :)

Comment: Curious .. what would prevent someone from asking if ANY word is in Tanac"h? Is there some boundary? What if I asked "Is the word "Shlemiel" in Tanac"h?" (It ALMOST is, BTW!)

Comment: @DanF, I think we have some requirements that a question have some basis for asking, but it is a broader question.

Comment: @Yishai I think that requirement is quite vague. It should be clarified. Unless you want me to be a potential pest just to prove a point (You like my alliteration?)

Comment: @DanF, sure, go for it. It should be asked as a separate question or discuss it here: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3784/what-should-we-do-with-does-judaism-permit-this-random-special-case-that-i-won

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how it is off topic and I've reopened it. We have reopen votes and peer review for a reason.